# Bash: How to reference a variable that contains another variable in its name?

Tags: bash, variables, syntax

I have a running variable, let's say it value is `INDEX = 1122` for the current iteration. I have exported:

`export PRO"$INDEX"=/some/fancy/dirry`

Now I want to reference to this variable, but if I do:

`echo $"PRO$INDEX"`

I get:

`PRO1122`

Instead I would like to see:

`/some/fancy/dirry`

Much like the result of `echo $PRO1122`.

However, I cannot of course hard code the value `1122` in the loop.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

BASH already has a variable reference mechanism.

You can do:

```
v="PRO$INDEX"
echo "${!v}"
/some/fancy/dirry
```

Answer (score 3):

Use `eval`:

```
eval echo '$PRO'$INDEX
```

But it seems like you should be using an array rather than embedding the index into the variable name.

Comment: `eval` should only be used for shells (like POSIX `sh`, which also lacks array support) that don't support some form of indirect parameter expansion.