# How to print a string in color, when a Variable has the actual color name?

Tags: bash, printf

I am trying to print a string with Specific color depending on the error code. Color varies on each error code, I am storing the actual color name in variable and using it in printf.

```
BLACK=$(tput setaf 0)
RED=$(tput setaf 1)
GREEN=$(tput setaf 2)
BLUE=$(tput setaf 4)
CYAN=$(tput setaf 5)
BOLD=$(tput bold)
NORMAL=$(tput sgr0)

# this color varies depending on error code
color=GREEN
```

```
printf "\${$color} This is a String ${NORMAL} \n"
```

But I get output as

```
${GREEN} This is a String
```

Expected output(In actual Green color)

```
This is a String
```

I can get this using

```
printf "${GREEN} This is a String ${NORMAL} \n"
```

But I want this output using color variable

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Bash: How to reference a variable that contains another variable in its name?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21938203/bash-how-to-reference-a-variable-that-contains-another-variable-in-its-name)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bash doesn't treat `${<variable>}` recursively inside strings, as you tried to do.

You can do `color=$<colorVariable>`, ie `color=$GREEN` before the `printf`, and then in the `printf` string doing `"$color This is a String ${NORMAL} \n"`

So, final result:

```
BLACK=$(tput setaf 0)
RED=$(tput setaf 1)
GREEN=$(tput setaf 2)
BLUE=$(tput setaf 4)
CYAN=$(tput setaf 5)
BOLD=$(tput bold)
NORMAL=$(tput sgr0)

# Event-dependant color
color=$GREEN

# And finally,
printf "$color This is a String ${NORMAL} \n"
```

There's another way you can do it.

```
# Define all colors, only GREEN and NORMAL here for brevity reasons
GREEN=$(tput setaf 2)
NORMAL=$(tput sgr0)

# Notice the missing $, as the original question
color=GREEN

# And then, use Bash's variable reference method (here notice both ! instead of $ and the missing \ at the beginning
printf "${!color} This is a String ${NORMAL} \n"
```

Answer (score 1):

How about:

```
color=$GREEN
```

And then:

```
printf "$color This is a String ${NORMAL} \n"
```

Gives me:

```
This is a String
```

in green.